# Find $P(min(X_A, X_B,X_C,X_D) = X_A)$

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, exponential-distribution

**Problem**

Four runners, A, B, C and D are organized in two teams, with runners A and B forming Team 1, and runners C and D forming Team 2. All four runners will run the same distance. Suppose that the running times of the 4 runners are all exponentially distributed, with respective means $µ_A$ = 9,$µ_B$ = 10, $µ_C$ = 8 and $µ_D$ = 12 minutes. Assume also that all four running times are independent.

What is the probability that the winner of the race (the fastest one of
the four runners) will come from Team 1?

**My Question**

To solve, I need to find $P(min(X_A, X_B,X_C,X_D) = X_A) + P(min(X_A, X_B,X_C,X_D) = X_B)$. I can find the pdf of $Z = min(X_A, X_B,X_C,X_D)$, but that won't tell me if $min(X_A, X_B,X_C,X_D) = X_A$, so I'm not sure how to proceed

Answer (score 1):

**HINT**

For independent, exponentially distributed random variables

$$P(\min(X_A,X_B,X_C,X_D)=X_A)=$$
$$=P(X_A\leq X_B\cap X_A\leq X_C\cap X_A\leq X_D)=$$
$$=E[P(X_A\leq X_B\cap _A\leq X_C\cap X_A\leq X_D\mid X_A)]=$$
$$=\int_0^{\infty}P(x\leq X_B\cap x\leq X_C\cap x\leq X_D\mid X_A=x)\lambda_Ae^{-\lambda_A x}dx=$$
$$=\int_0^{\infty}P(x\leq X_C)P(x\leq X_B)P(x\leq X_D)\lambda_Ae^{-\lambda_A x}\ dx=$$
$$=\int_0^{\infty}e^{-\lambda_B x}e^{-\lambda_C x}e^{-\lambda_D x}\lambda_Ae^{-\lambda_A x}\ dx=$$
$$=\int_0^{\infty}\lambda_Ae^{-(\lambda_A+\lambda_B+\lambda_C+\lambda_D)x}\ dx=$$
$$=\frac{\lambda_A}{\lambda_A+\lambda_B+\lambda_C+\lambda_D}.$$

Comment: Hmmm... $P(X_N\geqslant x)=e^{-\lambda_Nx}$ for every $X_N$ exponentially distributed with parameter $\lambda_N$ and every nonnegative $x$, not $1-e^{-\lambda_Nx}$.

Comment: why does $P(X_A≤X_B∩XA≤X_C∩X_A≤X_D)=E[P(X_A≤X_B∩X_A≤X_C∩XA≤X_D∣X_A)]$?

Comment: I'm not sure how to integrate the above formula since there are so many $e^{−λx}$ terms

Comment: @Did: oops, I am going to fix that.

Comment: @Alex: $E [X]=E [E[X\mid Y]]$ in general.

Comment: @Alex: I've fixed a bug. It is easier to integrate now.

Answer (score 1):

If $X\sim\mathrm{Exp}(\lambda)$ and $Y\sim\mathrm{Exp}(\mu)$ are independent, then 
\begin{align}
\mathbb P(X\leqslant Y) &= \int_0^\infty\int_0^y \lambda e^{-\lambda x}\mu e^{-\mu y}\ \mathsf dx\ \mathsf dy\\
&= \int_0^\infty \mu e^{-\lambda y}\left(1- e^{-\lambda y}\right)\ \mathsf dy\\
&= 1 - \mu\int_0^\infty e^{-(\lambda+\mu)y}\ \mathsf dy\\
&= \frac\lambda{\lambda+\mu}.
\end{align}
Moreover, for any $t>0$ we have
\begin{align}
\mathbb P(X\wedge Y>t) &= \mathbb P\left(\{X>t\}\cap\{Y>t\}\right)\\
&= \mathbb P(X>t)\mathbb P(Y>t)\\
&= e^{-\lambda t}e^{-\mu t}\\
&= e^{-(\lambda+\mu)t},
\end{align}
so that $X\wedge Y\sim\mathrm{Exp}(\lambda + \mu)$. Now,
$$
\{\min(X_A,X_B,X_C,X_D) = X_A \}\cup \{\min(X_A,X_B,X_C,X_D) = X_B \}
$$
is equivalent to 
$$
\{X_A\wedge X_B \leqslant \min(X_A,X_B,X_C,X_D)\},
$$
and thus we compute
\begin{align}
\mathbb P\left(\{X_A\wedge X_B \leqslant \min(X_A,X_B,X_C,X_D)\}\right) &= \frac{\frac19 + \frac1{10}}{\frac19 + \frac1{10}+\frac18+\frac1{12}}\\
&= \frac{76}{151}.
\end{align}